# How to See Computer's Clipboard?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

A common functionality behind cut, copy text from any editor is that it saves text in Computer's Clipboard and once you paste it, it gets that text from Clipboard (Temporary Storage) .
Is there any way to see the text which is copied in Clipboard from Computer. Backend Processing

Answer (score -1):

The clipboard is a feature provided by the operating system not the computer (hardware). A quick Google gives this link describing the clipboard programming interfaces for [Microsoft Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648709(v=vs.85).aspx), [X11 (Linux/FreeBSD)](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html) and [MacOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard